# Add new Wordpress user in the Subscriber role and automatically create a page for that user

Tags: wordpress

I am working with the following code that allows me to automatically create a page for a new user when they are added. I would to know how to create new pages only for users that were added to the Subscriber role.

Any help or links are appreciated.

```
/* Create New page for New User */

/* CREATE NEW POST WITH USER, GIVE POST USER'S NAME*/
function my_create_page($user_id){
$the_user = get_userdata($user_id);
$new_user_name = $the_user->user_login;
$my_post = array();
$my_post['post_title'] = $new_user_name;
$my_post['post_type'] = 'page';
$my_post['post_content'] = '';
$my_post['post_parent'] = '1569';
$my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
add_action('user_register', 'my_create_page');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the action 'profile_update' to create your page when the user role is changed.

```
<?php

    add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update', 10, 2 );

    function my_profile_update( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {
        // get user data
        $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
        $roles = $user_info->roles;
        if(in_array('subscriber', $roles)) {
          //create your page.
        }
    }
?>
```

if you need to perform the action on the user registration, you can do :

```
<?php

    add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

    function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id) {
        // get user data
        $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
        $roles = $user_info->roles;
        if(in_array('subscriber', $roles)) {
          //create your page.
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This could work! I could create a different role and we can change the user to that role to create the page. Still interested in finding a solution that wouldn't require the extra step. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! This worked perfectly. The other option is good to have too.